# How to make a call-to-action element for mobile?

Tags: website-design, gui-design, mobile, mobile-web, call-to-action

I am building a mobile website (lets say for for boutique hotels).
There will be a form, where users will be able to enter the hotel name,  email address, wanted dates etc...

Since I will also have some articles and content on my website, I would like to make a CTA ( call-to-action)/registration be available on all other pages as well.

Of course, I will not be able to put the full registration form on all the inner pages, so
 **What can I do?**

p.s. My idea was to put some "sticky" element, that will always be on the bottom, saying:
"Get your hotel now! [BOOK]". By clicking it, the user will go to the full form

- Is it a good idea?
- Is it a good idea to put a sticky element on the bottom of a mobile?
- **How to do such a small teaser that will lead to the full form?**

Comment: Please keep in mind that screen space on mobile devices is limited so the user mught be annoyed of the sticky is too big

Comment: Yep, but this is the only option I can think of so far...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a great idea; it saves space, lets the user get to it when desired, and increases engagement.

To answer your questions regarding justification, simply look at Stack Exchange sites. Nearly everywhere you navigate to in the interface, the "Ask a Question" button persists. Something similar on your site should be effective, if implemented correctly.

Comment: Thanks @Alan , as I see, the "sticky panel" is on top. Is it the usual thing to do to put it on top or on bottom?

Comment: And how is such an element called? I tried to google, but can't find the used name for such an element...

Comment: In this website's case, that area could be called a "header" or a "top-menu" in website-design terminology. At the bottom, that would be known as a "footer". To get the most engagement, placing the CTA at the top will be most effective, as users see it before they commit to reading the whole article. Placing one both at the top-and-bottom of length articles ensures the user sees the CTA if they read 0 or 100% of the article.

Answer (score 1):

You could also have a sticky element that expands into a form when clicked rather than redirecting to a new page.

Comment: Thank you @ryan. How would that be different?Only by the fact that the user will see some sort of animation while the form is expanded?

Comment: Yes, the user would see some sort of accordion animation as the form unfurled. It's not that different from a persistent button that takes them to the form page, but one less page load may be more convenient for some people.